# Non-spatial SQL Server table with X,Y fields directly in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql-server

In QGIS 3.6 I linked a SQL Server table with a field 'X' and a field 'Y', together representing positions in a known co-ordinate system.

How can I show these positions directly in QGIS, without having to use the tool 'Create points layer from table' in the Processing Toolbox (under 'Vector creation') and then using this points layer to view the data in the map?

Comment: create a view with the X,Y attributes converted into POINTS - ST_MAKEPOINT in postgis, sql-server must have a similar function.

Comment: Thanks. Does such a function exist (or work) in SQL Server 2005, which has no spatial functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a virtual layer in QGIS that builds the geometry. Changes to the data source should be reflected upon panning/refreshing the attribute table.

Go to the menu `layer / Add layer / Add-Edit virtual layer` and use `MakePoint(longitude, latitude, CRS)` to create the geometry :

```sql
select myID, myField, 
       MakePoint(myLong,myLat,3857) as geometry
from myTable
```

Comment: Hi. I did have the same problem - the solution worked but I cannot determine (setup) an extent for the virtual layer. The field seems to be greyed out and inactive. Without extent I cannot zoom in to a specific record which I would like to investigate.