# How to provide a point geometry to a table that has its origin in an ODBC connection?

Tags: qgis, geometry, odbc

The problem approach is as following:

1. A QGIS project has a table that comes from an ODBC connection referring to an MSAccess database.
2. To this table, a Join is configured with another layer through a key field. And this Join adds two new joined fields: XCOORD and YCOORD.

The requirement would be to turn this table into a points layer using the values from XCOORD and YCOORD fields. In addition, the other fields without geometry should be incorporated.

The idea would be that, every time the project is opened, the points layer would be live regenerated with the new changes that are made in the MSAccess database.

Comment: here is a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325847/non-spatial-sql-server-table-with-x-y-fields-directly-in-qgis/325860#325860) using a virtual layer